# Electron Firebase: FIREBASE WARNING: Provided authentication credentials are invalid

Tags: node.js, firebase, electron

I've created `electron` app that uses firebase auth and database.
App uses `signInWithCustomToken` with token received from remote server.
On my work machine (macOS) it works as expected. But when i've cloned my repo to home machine (windows) i've receive

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Provided authentication credentials are invalid. 
This usually indicates your FirebaseApp instance was not initialized correctly. 
Make sure your apiKey and databaseURL match the values provided 
for your app at https://console.firebase.google.com/
```

As i found here in same questions error with `firebase-admin`. But i'm using client library. Also i've misunderstood how it depends on machine where it runs?

I'm using npm package `firebase 4.1.5` packed with `webpack` into client script

Initialising:

```
const firebaseConf = {
  apiKey: '<api_key>',
  authDomain: '<domain>.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://<database>.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: '<project_id>',
  storageBucket: '<storage>.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '<sender_id>',
};

Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConf);
```

So on work machine all database operations work fine. But on home machine it shows that warning few times after `signInWithCustomToken` called and does nothing else 
The code is exactly the same. It was cloned from bitbucket

I've spent a whole day trying to figure out the reason but failed. 
Sorry for my English

Thank you in advance